# How to keep the first, min, max value from a semicolon-separated field in a table?

Tags: dataframe, awk, sed

I have a tab-delimited file with many semicolon separated values per field. **Here is the file:**

```
Name First Last
foo3;foo3;foo3;foo3;foo3    11869;12010;12179;12613;12613   12227;12057;12227;12721;12697
bar10;bar10;bar10   14404;15005;15796   14501;15038;15947
locM;locM;locM;locM 29554;30267;30564;30976 30039;30667;30667;31109
```

> **I would like to do the following [ in BASH or R ] with this file:**
>
> (1) In the first column, retain only one entry.
>
> (2) In the second column, keep only the *lowest* value from the
> semicolon-separated list of numbers.
>
> (3) In the third column, keep only the *highest* value from the
> semicolon-separated list of numbers.

**Here is the desired output:**

```
Name First Last
foo3    11869   12721
bar10   14404   15947
locM    29554   31109
```

It should be noted that the highest and lowest values are *not always* the first and last values in the semicolon-separated lists, respectively.

**Update (amateur ideas to solve the problem):**

- To address (1), I believe something like `awk -F";" 'BEGIN{ORS="/t"} !seen[$1]++' input.txt > output.txt` would be useful to remove
  duplicate instances, however I have not worked out how to write this
  completely.
- To address (2), I believe something similar to `cut -f2 -d"/t" input.txt > output.txt | cut -f1 -d";" | sort -n | head -1` will be
  able to select for the minimum number in the semicolon-separated
  list.
- To address (3), I believe something similar to `cut -f2 -d"/t" input.txt > output.txt | cut -f1 -d";" | sort -n | tail -1` will be
  able to select for the maximum number in the semicolon-separated
  list.

Comment: Users on this website are encourage to share their attempts

Comment: I second Paolo here, on SO all users are encouraged to show their efforts in form of code which they have put in order to solve their own problems. So kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then. BTW my answer is ready once you add efforts will add it cheers.

Comment: Very fair. I am quite new to coding, so admittedly I do not know exactly which tools will get me to the solution. I will obviously continue to investigate how to solve this problem on my own since I need to figure it out ASAP to move forward with this project. I figured posting here would be an efficient way for experienced coders to inform me [and others] of functions they might use to process their data in this way. I meant no harm, nor the abuse of this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested based on your shown samples only.

```
awk '
{
  split($1,array,";")
  num1=split($2,array1,";")
  num2=split($3,array2,";")
  min=array1[1]
  for(i=2;i<=num1;i++){
    min=(min<array1[i]?min:array1[i])
  }
  max=array2[1]
  for(i=2;i<=num2;i++){
    max=(max>array2[i]?max:array2[i])
  }
  print array[1],min,max
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                        ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  split($1,array,";")                                        ##Splitting 1st field into array with separator as ; here.
  num1=split($2,array1,";")                                  ##Splitting 2nd field into array1 with separator as ; here.
  num2=split($3,array2,";")                                  ##Splitting 3rd field into array2 with separator as ; here.
  for(i=1;i<=num1;i++){                                      ##Running for loop till vale of num1 which is total elements in array1.
    min=(min<array1[i]?(min?min:array1[i]):array1[i])        ##Creating min here which is using ternary operator to check if current element of array1 is lesser than min then keep it else keep min current value and so on comparing each element one by one here.
  }
  for(i=1;i<=num2;i++){                                      ##Running for loop till value of mun2 which is total elements in array2.
    max=(max>array2[i]?max:array2[i])                        ##Creating max here using ternary operator checks if max value greater than array2 current value then keep it as it is else assign current value of array2 to max here.
  }
  print array[1],min,max                                     ##Printing 1st element of array then min and max here.
  min=max=""                                                 ##Nullifying variables min and max here.
}'  Input_file                                               ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: This is really great @RavinderSingh13! Thank you very much. I can confirm it works with my dataset.

Comment: Please note that in the min computation, any positive value following a zero min would overwrite the min. The inner condition is not hard to fix but initializing the min/max to the first item (like in Ed's answer) is more robust IMO.

Comment: What @luciole75w said applies to the max calculation too otherwise it'll fail when all input values are negative, and the `min?min:array1[i]` part of your current min calculation will fail when the min value is zero - it'll set min to the lowest value greater than zero after the zero was detected.

Comment: @EdMorton, Thank you sir and thank you Iuciole75w  for letting know. Sir could you please do suggest on same, if you have top of your head else I will take a look late in night sir :) thank you again and cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 you're welcome. I updated the uncommented script for you, I left the commented one as-is because I'm too lazy to rewrite the comments (and so it's easy for you to see what changed)! The rule is that for any min or max calculations you should always init the min/max variables to the first value read.

Comment: @EdMorton, appreciate your help sir, thank you for fixing it sorry I am in back to back prod issues really couldn't think of it, thanks a TON sir for your help here thank you cheers

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR == 1 { print; next }
{ print val($1,1), val($2,"min"), val($3,"max") }

function val(str,type,  vals,min,max) {
    split(str,vals,/;/)
    min = max = vals[1]
    for (i in vals) {
        if (vals[i] < min) {
            min = vals[i]
        }
        if (vals[i] > max) {
            max = vals[i]
        }
    }
    if      ( type == "min" ) return min
    else if ( type == "max" ) return max
    else                      return vals[type]
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Name    First   Last
foo3    11869   12721
bar10   14404   15947
locM    29554   31109
```

That `val()` function can return the value at whatever position you want in the sub-fields, not just the first, and obviously it can easily be enhanced to return any other type of information you need to extract from the sub fields, e.g. the average.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed and Bash):

```
sed -E '1b;s/([^;]*).*\t(.*)\t(.*)/echo "\1\t$(echo "\2"|tr ";" "\\n"|sort -n |head -1)\t$(echo "\3"|tr ";" "\\n"|sort -n |tail -1)"/e' file
```

Do not process the headings.

Split each data line into three columns delimited by tabs (fields within columns are delimited by `;`):

1. Reduce the first column to first field of that column.
2. Sort the second column numerically and keep only the first field i.e. the minimum.
3. Sort the third column numerically and keep only the last field i.e. the maximum.

Achieve this by evaluating the RHS of substitution command using the `e` flag.